# How to fix black tooltips in Eclipse?

Tags: 11.04, eclipse

I am having a weird problem with Eclipse documentation tooltips. When I startup Eclipse the tooltip works as expected:

[image]

But after I press the <kbd>down</kbd> button the tooltip turns black:

[image]

and stays like that for the rest of the session.

I am using Eclipse Galileo and Ubuntu 11.04 with the classic desktop.

**EDIT:**  I am only experiencing this problem in PHP Development Tools. The tooltips work in Java and Python projects.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer from Arkaduysz's works if you correct the second line. the gksu would try to change root's settings I think.:

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser
```

run it:

```
gnome-color-chooser
```

Go to "Specific" tab, check and setup background/foreground colors in tooltip box. Apply & Close.

To fix the color issue in the eclipse package explorer (white font on light grey back), choose "global" tab, and check standard > inputfield > selected and set it to black.

Comment: this also worked for me to fix gnome applications running in KDE (gimp, UFRaw, etc). For some reason the setting "Apply colors to non-Qt applications" in the `Colors` menu wasn't having any effect for me.

Comment: This is the easiest way to fix this without manually hacking into gtk css files. Thanks!

Comment: That seemed to have ceased to work with Eclipse Oxygen. (I have the color chooser installed and black-on-yellow for tooltips, but Eclipse shows still black background for tooltips.)

Answer (score 15):

To fix this annoying behaviour in KDE, the fix is similar:

- run `System Settings`
- Click on `Application Appearance` in `Common Appearance and Behaviour`
- Click on `Colours` icon and then on `Colours` tab
- Find `Tooltip Background` and choose a bright color, for instance pale yellow or white
- Find `Tooltip Text` below and choose a darker color, like blue or black
- Click `Apply`

The fix will be available immediately, no need to restart Eclipse.

**Note:** On Eclipse mars the change was not immediate. I had to restart eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! One note is that you do need to restart Eclipse (just the editors actually, but if you have a lot of them open...) with Eclipse Juno and Kubuntu 12.10 for all tooltips to change.

Comment: I finally had to resort to this - changing tooltip bg to white, and text to black, ten restart Eclipse Mars. Other apps (chromium browser) worked well with only this change: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=295486 (don't apply scheme to apps from outside KDE - in Kubuntu).

Answer (score 6):

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-chooser
```

run it:

```
gnome-color-chooser
```

Go to "Specific" tab, check and setup background/foreground colors in tooltip box. Apply & Close.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this problem by switching to the Radiance theme and then setting the tool-tip color in Appearance/Customize.../Colors:

[image]

When I tried the same thing with the Ambiance theme I started getting weird color errors all over my desktop.

Comment: Neither of Ambience nor Radience work for me, even after changing colors in `gnome-color-chooser`. However, the Adwaita theme works out of the box, without using `gnome-color-chooser` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/70665/145754) *finally* worked for me after trying several other solutions, none of which worked (Eclipse Mars 4.5.2, Ubuntu 14.04.3). I did have to edit one additional file though (`gtk-main.css`).

If you run the "Ambiance" theme (default theme, dark), open these files and change all "bg" tooltip colors to `#ffffff` (white) and all "fg" tooltip colors to `#000000` (black):

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

So e.g. run:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

If you run the "Radiance" theme (the light theme), you need to edit these files:

```
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

So e.g. run:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix Eclipse tooltip color without falling back to GTK2 and without affecting any other application.

The fix is captured in a script and it can be accessed here.

https://github.com/KiranMohan/eclipse-gtk3-ubuntu

The script makes a copy of the Ambiance theme, modifies the tooltip color and then writes a launcher for eclipse with this new Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this in Oxygen by going to `windows`->`preferences`->`general`->`appearance`->`Colors and Fonts` then in the window provided find `Javadoc background (overrides default)` - changing the color to anything that is not black.