# How to change tooltip background color in Unity?

Tags: unity, themes

In a lot of applications the tooltips are just plain ugly (White text on black background, way too much contrast) or even unreadable (black or dark blue text (Hyperlinks) on black background). I want to change the background color of the tooltips to some medium gray or even some yellow or something like that, maybe even something semi-transparent.

Here is a screenshot of Eclipse which displays some source code in a tool tip with black text on black background:

[image: Eclipse with an unusable tooltip]

Switching to a different theme (Something other than Ambiance or Radiance) helps but I like Ambiance and I want to keep it. It's just this darn tooltip color which is absolutely unacceptable.

I found several solutions for older Ubuntu versions but they no longer work with Unity in Ubuntu 11.10 because I can't find any function to customize the Ambiance or Radiance theme. So how do I do that in the current Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Found it!

I had to edit these files:

```
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

(Addition: for Ubuntu 12.04, it seems youjust have to modify the file:
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc , replacing the tooltip backround and foreground color, with the #000000 and the #f5f5b5 color, respectively)

You require root privileges to edit the files. Use `gksudo gedit` to edit them.

Search for `tooltip` in these files and you'll find the color definitions for the foreground and the background. I use `#000000` as foreground and `#f5f5b5` as background and now the tooltips in all applications are again readable. After changing the color values simply switch to some other theme and then back to Ambiance and the tooltip color is now fixed.

Here is the result:

[image: Eclipse with customized theme]

Comment: Could you please include how you setup your configuration or an example of a configuration? This would help other wanting the same more.

Comment: What exactly is missing in my description? I listed the files which must be edited and for what term you have to search. You'll find the color values and have to change them to something you like, then save the files and reload the theme. That's it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. It's a perfectly fine answer. I was just suggestion to include the full entry to change (e.g. to show how it looks before and after change). Being explicit is good.

Comment: any way to do this via the UI in ubuntu 11?

Comment: Also, you have to restart Eclipse after that.

Comment: it should be `gksudo` and not `sudo`.

Comment: Worked just as expected in Xubuntu 12.10 as well.

Comment: Is there a way to change this for your user only (ie, not require `[gk]sudo`? I'm sure that, as most gnome settings, there is a per-user config file/dir

Comment: @MestreLion: User themes are picked from `~/.themes/`. You will need to copy the Ambiance folder into this.

Comment: I had to edit `gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` as well, but this worked on 14.04. Also works when using the "Radiance" theme, just need to edit the same files in the `Radiance` folder.

Comment: the reason of editing `gtk-main.css` is that `gtk.css` is simply including `gtk-main.css`: `@import url("gtk-main.css");`

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 (as mentioned for 12.04), you can also get away with only editing /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc and replacing the tooltip backround and foreground color, with #000000 and #f5f5b5, respectively.

Answer (score 149):

Install and open [gnome-color-chooser [image: Install gnome-color-chooser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-color-chooser).

Go to `Specific` → `Tooltips` and put black foreground over pale yellow background.

Comment: restart eclipse for changes to take effect

Comment: No need to restart for me.

Comment: This works for 12.04 LTS with Eclipse 4.2 too!

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and Eclipse Juno). Both, the accepted answer and the one below from DJo, worked for me.

Comment: +1, but note that this affects ALL of the system tooltips. If you want a solution just for Eclipse, follow @bain's answer.

Comment: +1, I had this problem with eclipse for more than a year in different ubuntu releases... even at work... this was the most annoying problem I ever had in ubuntu... thx vm!

Comment: This is not working for Xubuntu with XFCE?..

Comment: not working in `16.04`. kayahr answer works well

Answer (score 30):

If you want to change the tooltip colors for all apps then install and run *gnome-color-chooser* and go to Specific tab > Tooltips. Check the boxes for Foreground and Background and choose colors.

How it works (you can do this manually):

gnome-color-chooser adds the following to your ~/.gtkrc-2.0:

```
include ".gtkrc-2.0-gnome-color-chooser"
```

and ~/.gtkrc-2.0-gnome-chooser:

```
style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
```

If you just want to change the tooltip colors for a single app, such as eclipse, then put the above text into a custom gtkrc file (e.g. ~/gtkrc-eclipse) and start eclipse with *GTK2_RC_FILES=~/gtkrc-eclipse eclipse*

Comment: Here is the setting to customize the **background color of the autocompletion dialog** in Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8063723/356895.

Comment: Do you know how I can **include the environment variable in the Ubuntu application menu** so Eclipse also loads the settings when not started via the shell?

Comment: I compiled an [article](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/) which summarizes the topic.

Comment: fantastic approach @bain !!! :)Does not require `sudo`, affects your user only, and does not need to copy the whole theme to your `~`. Nice :)

Comment: @JJD: I'm usually against "thank you"-only comments, but your article is awesome. I noticed it uses the same approach as this answer. Since I already use a custom shell script to launch Eclipse from both command line and .desktop file, adding the GTK2_RC_FILES=... env is easy. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, What do you mean start eclipse with GTK2_RC_FILES=~/gtkrc-eclipse eclipse ?

Comment: @AKh It means you would type that command in a terminal to run eclipse with the environment variable GTK2_RC_FILES set. See [why is setting a variable before a command legal in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126938/why-is-setting-a-variable-before-a-command-legal-in-bash) for a description of the syntax, it's just a way to temporarily set one or more environment variables for the execution of a program, in this case to force GTK to load the style file you created.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 with Eclipse Mars this does not work :(

Answer (score 23):

I created a small script that does that for you

```
#/bin/sh
# Tooltip fix
# A script to fix themes files in Ubuntu 11.10
#  to have readable tooltips in applications such
#  as eclipse.
# The script edits the gtk.css, settings.ini and gtkrc files
# Author: Victor Pillac
# http://victorpillac.wordpress.com

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi  

path=/usr/share/themes
theme=Ambiance

if [ $# = 1 ]; then
  theme=$1
fi

echo "Fixing tooltips for theme $theme"
echo " (you can select a different theme by passing its name as argument)"
sed -i 's/tooltip_bg_color #000000/tooltip_bg_color #f5f5b5/g' $path/$theme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
sed -i 's/tooltip_fg_color #ffffff/tooltip_fg_color #000000/g' $path/$theme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
sed -i 's/tooltip_bg_color:#000000/tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5/g' $path/$theme/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
sed -i 's/tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff/tooltip_fg_color:#000000/g' $path/$theme/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
sed -i 's/tooltip_bg_color:#000000/tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5/g' $path/$theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
sed -i 's/tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff/tooltip_fg_color:#000000/g' $path/$theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 9):

I've adopted a slightly different solution;

First create a new script, eclipse.sh, that starts eclipse, mine look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/eclipse/gtkrc-2.0-eclipse /usr/share/eclipse/eclipse
```

Then create the gtkrc file (/usr/share/eclipse/gtkrc-2.0-eclipse), mine look like this (it have some other changes as well to make better use of the screen):

```
style "my-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "my-tooltips"

style "gtkcompact" 
{
    font_name="Ubuntu Light 11"

    GtkButton::default_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButton::default_outside_border={0,0,0,0}
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_width=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_min_heigth=0
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_x=4
    GtkButtonBox::child_internal_pad_y=4
    GtkMenu::vertical-padding=1
    GtkMenuBar::internal_padding=0
    GtkMenuItem::horizontal_padding=4
    GtkToolbar::internal-padding=1
    GtkToolbar::space-size=1
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_size=0
    GtkOptionMenu::indicator_spacing=0
    GtkPaned::handle_size=4
    GtkRange::trough_border=0
    GtkRange::stepper_spacing=0
    GtkScale::value_spacing=0
    GtkScrolledWindow::scrollbar_spacing=0
    GtkExpander::expander_size=10
    GtkExpander::expander_spacing=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::horizontal-separator=0
    GtkTreeView::expander-size=10
    GtkTreeView::fixed-height-mode=TRUE
    GtkWidget::focus_padding=0
    GtkTreeView::vertical-separator = 0
}

class "GtkWidget" style "gtkcompact"

style "gtkcompactextra" 
{
    xthickness=0
    ythickness=0
}

class "GtkButton"   style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkToolbar"  style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkPaned"    style "gtkcompactextra"
class "GtkNotebook" style "gtkcompact"
```

Answer (score 8):

For CDT do the following:

Window>Preferences>C/C++>Editor: Appearance Color Options>Source Hover Background

Uncheck System Default, and select a color.

Unfortunately there's no Eclipse-wide setting that I know of. Pretty lame. You shouldn't have to set stuff like that for every perspective.

Answer (score 7):

I think this one is solved. I got it showing the tooltip with black letters on white background. In my case, it seems that Eclipse is using settings fot tooltips from `gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file from theme directory.

My setup: Ubuntu 12.04, Gnome (Not Unitiy), Eclipse Indigo (3.7), GrayDay theme for Gnome. The name of theme and theme itself is not importat.

Open the terminal, change to the theme directory (cd $HOME/.themes) and there, go to the directory of your theme. If your .themes direcotry if empty of it doesn't exist, then, you are using system theme which is in  /usr/share/themes. Just figure out the name of the theme you are using (right click on bakcground, choose Change Desktop Background, the theme name should be in the lower right corner. If it says nothing about theme name, then use gnome-tweak-tool to find out which theme you are using).

In the theme directory, issue this command:

```
grep -r tooltip *
```

it should list all of the files and lines where keywork "tooltip" is mentioned. Change every background (tooltip_bg_color) to #ffffff and every foreground to #000000. Black latters on white foreground, this is what we want! Especially, change values in the `gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file.

Mistake I was doing, is chainging tooltip color in the gtk-3.0 directory, which didn't have any effect.

Now, go to the Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor and set Source Hover Background to the "System color" (check on the right). Restart the Eclipse!

This is listig of `grep -r tooltip *` from my theme directory after doing changes:

```
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:gtk-color-scheme  = "tooltip_fg_color:#000000\ntooltip_bg_color:#ffffff\nlink_color:#0033ff"
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:style "tooltips" {
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:  bg[NORMAL]  = @tooltip_bg_color
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:  fg[NORMAL]  = @tooltip_fg_color
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:  GtkWidget::new-tooltip-style    = 0
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:# The window of the tooltip is called "gtk-tooltip"
gtk-2.0/gtkrc:widget "gtk-tooltip*"             style "tooltips"
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:/* @define-color tooltip_bg_color #343434; */
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:/* @define-color tooltip_fg_color #ffffff; */
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:@define-color tooltip_bg_color #ffffff;
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:@define-color tooltip_fg_color #343434;
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:@define-color theme_tooltip_bg_color @tooltip_bg_color;
gtk-3.0/gtk.css:@define-color theme_tooltip_fg_color @tooltip_fg_color;
gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:.tooltip {
gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    background-color:   @theme_tooltip_bg_color;
gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    color:              shade(@theme_tooltip_fg_color, 0.90);
gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:.tooltip * {
gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css:    background-color: @theme_tooltip_bg_color;
gtk-3.0/settings.ini:gtk-color-scheme   = "tooltip_fg_color:#343434\ntooltip_bg_color:#ffffff\nlink_color:#4a90d9"
gtk-3.0/settings-default.ini:gtk-color-scheme   = "tooltip_fg_color:#343434\ntooltip_bg_color:#ffffff\nlink_color:#4a90d9"
```

Comment: It was actually enough to follow jgreen's answer and change only one line in one file.

Answer (score 4):

There is also another solution to this:
use dconf-editor to find the following key:

```
org->gnome->desktop->interference->gtk-color-scheme
```

whose description said:
A `\n` separated list of `name:color` as defined by the `gtk-color-scheme` setting.

Write the scheme in gedit in the style likes the following(this example is mine), then paste it in the dconf-editor(notice the '\n' at each end of the line):

```
fg_color:#4c4c4c4c4c4c
bg_color:#f2f2f1f1f0f0
text_color:#3c3c3c3c3c3c
base_color:#ffffffffffff
selected_fg_color:#ffffffffffff
selected_bg_color:#f0f077774646
tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff5a0e74
tooltip_bg_color:#14a784edd8b6
```

and the problem will be solved immediately.

Comment: org->gnome->desktop->interface->gtk-color-scheme

Comment: Like the new Reference: 

GtkSettings:gtk-color-scheme has been deprecated since version 3.8 and should not be used in newly-written code.

Color scheme support was dropped and is no longer supported. You can still set this property, but it will be ignored.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 is not anymore valid. I tried to change it by dconf but with no results. In Ubuntu 18.04 you have to change the gtk-3.0 folder in .config putting your gtk.css file in order to take effect. You have to modify even the seettings.ini in that folder.

Answer (score 4):

My tooltips are black-on-yellow. See screenshot below from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with MATE DE:

[image: Black-on-Yellow tooltip]

If you like such color combination, use 2 gtkrc (1 for GTK3, 1 for GTK2) files below:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0/
cat << EOF >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
/* tooltips */
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #ffffaf;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #000000;
tooltip label,
.tooltip label {
    text-shadow: none;
}
EOF
cat << EOF >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
[Settings]
gtk-color-scheme = "tooltip_bg_color:#ffffaf\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000"
EOF

cat << EOF >> ~/.gtkrc-2.0
style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
{
  bg[NORMAL] = "#FFFFAF"
  fg[NORMAL] = "#000000"
}
widget "gtk-tooltip*" style "gnome-color-chooser-tooltips"
EOF
```

The 3rd file is only for GTK2-based applications.

The method above was tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Unity and GNOME), Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Unity, GNOME, MATE), Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Unity, GNOME, MATE), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (MATE).

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 the third and fourth part are not useful because it uses Gtk-3.0. First and second one solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was having same problem (Xubuntu 12.04, Greybird theme, Eclipse Indigo) and Mihael K's answer worked for me.
The only file I changed was gtk-2.0/gtkrc and I only changed one line. 
The third line after the initial comments. Changed the hex color values of tooltip_bg_color:#000000 to tooltip_bg_color:#ffffe1 and tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff to tooltip_fg_color:#000000. So the line will look like this:

```
gtk_color_scheme        = "tooltip_bg_color:#ffffe1\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000" # Tooltips.
```

Restarted elipse and tooltips are now the yellowish color I'm accustomed to. I didn't need to do any further tweaks in eclipse or any of the other files.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) you can use the following two commands:

```
#foreground white => black
sudo sed -i s/tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff/tooltip_fg_color:#000000/g  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
#background black => yellow
sudo sed -i s/tooltip_bg_color:#000000/tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5/g  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

(Thanks to the other answers that helped me to figure this out!!)

Answer (score 0):

A more user-friendly way to change the background is using the UI. Open System, Preferences, Appearance. By default "Ambiance" theme will be selected, but you can change it for any theme. Click on Customize button below and switch to Colors tab. There you can change foreground and background colors for tooltips by clicking on appropriate boxes.

Comment: On 11.10, this does not work. I can change the theme in Appearance, but there is no means to customize the theme.

Comment: I don't have 11.10 installed but I would find it weird if they have removed a way to customize a theme. Perhaps they have renamed the button and/or placed it in a different place/tab?

Comment: Sergiy, many of us have searched but it looks like it's not there. We're hoping it will reappear in 12.04.

Comment: Are you guys *really* surprised about removed customization options in Gnome3/Unity?

Comment: Not anymore... after using 12.04 for a while, our admins are considering moving onto Fedora or some other RHEL-like distribution. Ubuntu has become a multimedia platform, which works well for home users, but not for the IT professionals.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to point out a rare case where a very similar bug occurs if you have installed xulrunner and configured eclipse to use it.

I installed xulrunner to make the GPE Designer to properly render GWT UIs in the design mode, which worked very well but I found it also broke the tooltips. The bug is actually worse than the screenshot above, it just display a blank tooltip.

To fix it you only have to remove the xulrunner parameter from `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/path/to/xulrunner/
```

It worked for me with Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse 4.2/Juno and xulrunner 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

**For elementary users:**

Go to `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0`, edit the file `gtk-widgets.css` with `sudo nano`, type `Ctrl + W` to find `Tooltips`, and then at the `background-color: alpha(#color, #opacity)` change the color to something like `#f5f5b5` and set opacity to 1.

Answer (score 0):

To open Appearance window with Tab: Themes direct from root@ terminal write (you can use this command also for script):

```
sudo -u USER gnome-appearance-properties -p theme
```

where `USER` is your current user on the desktop. It will open Appearance correctly, but you still need to click on theme displays in Appearance window to launch your theme.

For the test with install theme: Dust from root@ terminal, command:

```
sudo -u USER gnome-appearance-properties -i /home/USER/Desktop/Dust-0.4.tar.gz
```

gets this error:

> (gnome-appearance-properties:16161): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"

but if theme: Dust is installing by chosing menu: System/Preferences/Appearance and installs from Appearance window , installation of the theme: Dust is correct.

There is needed command responsible for choosing themes in Appearance window, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 with the Breeze theme, and Eclipse 4.6.1 with the default GTK3 now that they've fixed the button padding issue.

To attain hover tooltips with light grey background and black foreground I made a few changes to `/usr/share/themes/Breeze-gtk/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`; here's what I ended up with:

```
/************
 * Tooltips *
 ************/
.tooltip {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tooltip.background {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

And the original:

```
/************
 * Tooltips *
 ************/
.tooltip {
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  /* not working */
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px black; }
  .tooltip.background {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }
```

In case links aren't working in Javadoc popups, it may help to install `libwebkitgtk` like so:

```
sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```