# How to change web browser's tab bar background color or image?

Tags: unity, 12.04, themes

Running Precise. I am tweaking the ambiance theme to my taste. 
Yet I can't locate where I can modify the **background color of the browser's tab bar** (I suspect its value instruction to be somewhere in the gtk-widget or gtk-3 style files). See image:
[image: Web browser tab bar background color]

Thanks in advance.

------------------**-EDIT--**---------------------

Solution:

Edited the following files:

- /usr/share/themes/MyTheme/gtk-2.0/apps/chromium.rc (  style "chrome-gtk-frame"{ ...})
- gtk.css
- **gtkrc** (gtk-2.0 folder / first line of style dark - background - ) :

---

```
style "dark"
{
    color["bg_color_dark"]  = "#303030"   #original was 3c3b37
    color["fg_color_dark"]  = "#dfdbd2"
    color["selected_fg_color_dark"] = "#ffffff"

fg[NORMAL]        = @fg_color_dark
fg[PRELIGHT]      = shade (1.15, @fg_color_dark)
fg[ACTIVE]    = @fg_color_dark
fg[SELECTED]      = @selected_fg_color_dark
fg[INSENSITIVE]   = shade (0.5, @fg_color_dark)

bg[NORMAL]        = @bg_color_dark
bg[ACTIVE]    = shade (0.8, @bg_color_dark)
bg[SELECTED]      = @selected_bg_color
bg[PRELIGHT]      = shade (1.0, "#4D4C48")
bg[INSENSITIVE]   = shade (0.85, @bg_color_dark)

text[NORMAL]      = @fg_color_dark
text[PRELIGHT]    = shade (1.15, @fg_color_dark)
text[SELECTED]    = @selected_fg_color_dark
text[ACTIVE]      = @fg_color_dark
text[INSENSITIVE] = mix (0.5, @bg_color, @bg_color_dark)
```

}

**RESULT:**

[image: Modified Browsers tab bar Background color]

Comment: Congrats on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? :)

Comment: I would love to see ASKUBUNTU implementing the ability to choose more than one answer. In this case, answers from titaniumtux and fragos are both similar to me and were posted at the same time.

Comment: possibly - that is the reason why we have upvotes and adding bounties to good answers.  However at the moment, your "question" is actually an excellent answer - so please add it as an answer and let us upvote you.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hanynowsky how to dao that with gtk3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to edit the desktop colors? No graphic way to do it in Ubuntu 11.10/12.04.

1. Execute `gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`
2. Don't like orange? Change the value of `selected_bg_color`. Feel free to change the other colors using HTML colors.
3. Save and exit, effects will kick in eventually.

This should set the background color for Chrome/Chromium.

See [How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

Install the chrome plugin from below link .. you should be able to make your own themes .. and change colors ..

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oehpjpccmlcalbenfhnacjeocbjdonic?utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=mychrometheme&utm_source=en-et-na-us-et-mychrometheme

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was interested in tweaking the Ambiance theme and applying settings to all browsers I use (Firefox and Chromium). I am satisfied with the actual Chromium theme, I just needed to apply a style setting in OS level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably sure the color choices in both Chrome and Chromium are a function of a theme which only covers this application. Application that run on multiple desktop environment frequently don't avail themselves of the desktop themes. To change colors for applications written for Gnome's GTK you'll need to change gtkrc for applications not yet upgraded to GTK 3.0 and for the GTK 3.0 applications you'll need to edit setting.ini and gtk.css in the gtk-3.0 folder. All three files use the same labels for the colors values. They all should be changed to the same values. At least this is the case for the Ambiance theme.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a native Chrome solution as well**:

GoTo settings and activate "Use GTK+ Design".