# How to change bgcolor of active tab in chrome/chromium?

Tags: themes, google-chrome, chromium, gtk-2

This question complements the question [How to change web browser's tab bar background color or image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118357/how-to-change-web-browsers-tab-bar-background-color-or-image)

It seems changing the whole tab bar bgcolor is not difficult, but **how about changing the bgcolor of the active tab**?

It's especially necessary when you choose light monochrome icons for your dark theme, i.e. when those light icons are difficult to see in the active tab, toolbar, etc. of chrome/chromium, as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Chrome to use your GTK theme.  This post also has good instructions:

[How to change web browser's tab bar background color or image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118357/how-to-change-web-browsers-tab-bar-background-color-or-image)