# How do I change the color and font of PDF comments in Evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

Evince now handles comments written in other pdf markup software (e.g. Adobe), which is very nice.  Unfortunately, it chooses a yellow font on a white background that is almost impossible to read (though highlighting the comment with the mouse helps).  Is there any way to change this behavior?

[image]

(Adobe's acroread displays these correctly but is terribly slow and not a native open-source, so I'd prefer a different alternative).

Comment: try solution for this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity ,I don't have 12.04 to verify it

Comment: Thanks -- the theme settings do change the overall color (i.e. switching themes does change the note appearance -- but not to anything that can be read easily other than the ugly high-contrast theme), but unfortunately I cannot tell what to toggle in gnome-color-picker or the config file to change the background of the notes, it's not the same toggle as for tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed very quickly the source code but couldn't find a way to change it or propose a patch, but I will try to do it later.

Anyway, for the time being I made a bug report on the proper place https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677471 so now we wait if it is answered by the team.

Comment: It's because of the Ambiance theme does not support the right colors. If you use the Adwaita theme then the text is black. (Thanks to jnfbtista for making the bug report.) This is just a workaround.

Comment: just changed to Adwaita theme. i cant believe a standard theme causes those hard troubles... + that prob is at least half a year old. ;<

Comment: Any way to tweak Ambiance to fix this?