# How can I change the Eclipse tooltip background color from black to white?

Tags: 12.04, unity, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity)

It's hard to read tooltips in Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04; how can I change the colors? Before Ubuntu 12.04, it could be changed with tooltip system color in "Appearances". How could I do this in 12.04?

Fixed:
[How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) - all I need.