# How do I change system colors in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, colors

I am looking to customize my system, making it look a little more pleasing to my eyes, and I know I have seen an article somewhere, but I can't seem to find it anymore, on how do I change the color of the close icon in Unity on 12.04? Does anyone know how I can do this, as well as change other system colors?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/70599/62483 or http://askubuntu.com/q/116/62483

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called MyUnity that allows you to change color schemes and install any GTK theme you like.

http://www.uielinux.org/myunity/