# How can I fix 12.10 Theme changes that make unreadable dialogs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, 12.10

Changes in window themes of something of the sort is causing the popup dialogs in Eclipse to have a very dark background.  Then, since Eclipse uses hyperlinks in dialogs, I get blue on black, and it's basically unreadable.  I tried changing themes in Ubuntu Tweak, but nothing seemed to affect the background color of that dialog.  Can anyone help?

What I'm looking at:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/319mj.jpg

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse can use GTK themes but it is an option, it's not obligatory.
Go to Preferences, General->Appearence. Select "Classic" in Theme instead of GTK.
Restart eclipse and you should be happy with the result.

Cheers :)

Comment: +1 Classic looks much better than the Gtk themes. It also fixes the problem that I can't read the heap status when "Default" is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I use Kubuntu 12.10.

I fix this problem with change color of tooltips background and change color of text tooltips.

Comment: To change the colors, open "System Settings" -> "Application Appearance" -> Colors -> Colors -> "Tooltip Background"

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) you can use the following two commands:

```
#foreground white => black
sudo sed -i s/tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff/tooltip_fg_color:#000000/g  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
#background black => yellow
sudo sed -i s/tooltip_bg_color:#000000/tooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5/g  /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk.css /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

(Thanks to the other answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) that helped me to figure this out)