# Where are theme settings stored?

Tags: themes, kde, settings, lxde

I installed Ubuntu with several Desktop Environments, including Unity, KDE and LXDE.

I am struggling to change the background tooltip color which is black and causes displaying problems in Eclipse.

I managed to do this in Unity as explained here: [How to change tooltip background color in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity)

I was unable to do this in LXDE. However when I changed the tooltip background color from KDE GUI settings (System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Colors), the change was also reflected in LXDE, so I assume there must be a configuration file from which all desktop environments read this information.

Where are theme settings stored?

Answer (score 2):

**KDE**

The KDE is saving the own settings to the /home/[user]/.kde/...

The color settings are saved to the /1/:

> Colors
>
> The colors file follows the standard KDE colorscheme file format and
>   allows a theme to define what colors work best with its theme
>   elements...
>
> Saved at /home/[user]/.kde/share/apps/color-schemes/[unique
>   name].colors ...

If you are editing the "current" color scheme then the settings are saved to the kdeglobals file - /home/[user]/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals.

**Links**

1. http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/ThemeDetails

Comment: Ok! But why KDE settings are reflected in LXDE? Where LXDE stores its color settings?

Comment: I have not used the LXDE so this is a pure quess. With the KDE there are GTK+ engines to ensures visual consistency between GTK+ and Qt-based applications running under the KDE. Maybe the LXDE is having something like that.

Comment: Or maybe KDE is updating GTK+ theme settings to unsure this consistency.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is GTK theme settings which is used by GTK applications in KDE and other desktop environments (Unity, LXDE, ..):

```
~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

**Source:** [Is there a way to stop KDE from overwriting my other WM settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253751/is-there-a-way-to-stop-kde-from-overwriting-my-other-wm-settings)