# Some programs (Eclipse) show their tooltips with an unfitting black background

Tags: themes, gui, text, design

Here is a tooltip from Eclipse, that pops open when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>:

[image]

Is this intentional? White text on black background does not exactly fit in, and it would be much more readable if it used some standard theme.

Can I make it so?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: @TheSchwa Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: See if either of these help  http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity, http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#Black_background_color_for_tooltips_on_Linux.2FUbuntu.2FGTK