# GTK3 and GTK2 tooltip background color difference

Tags: 14.04, gtk, gtk3, gtk-2

I changed the tool tip background color setting in my current theme **Ambiance** for gtk-2 and gtk-3.0.

Even though I used the same color code #f5f5c5 the tool tip background color in eclipse and gedit(uses GTK3) and Firefox(which uses GTK2) are displayed differently.

See image

[image]

Please some one let me know the color code to be used for gtk-3.0 applications so that it looks same as shown in firefox?

GTK3 changes:

**In /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:**

> [Settings]
>   gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nbg_color:#f2f1f0\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_fg_color:#ffffff\nlink_color:#DD4814\nbg_color_dark:#3c3b37\nfg_color_dark:#dfdbd2"

**In /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css:**

....

@define-color tooltip_bg_color #f5f5c5;

@define-color tooltip_fg_color #000000;

....

GTK2 changes:

**In /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc file:**

> gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#F2F1F
>   0\ntooltip_bg_color:#ffffaf\nlink_color:#DD4814"

Comment: Maybe eclipse isn't a gtk2 or a gtk3 app. In which case, tweaking your gtk2/gtk3 theme may not help? Try searching the net for "eclipse themes".

Comment: No I am sure that eclipse uses GTK3, because as and when I change GTK3 settings, I can see the changes in tooltip color. But my problem is the color code is not uniform, I am expecting colors like in GTK2

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393409, and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/eclipse#Tooltips_have_dark_background_color_with_Gnome_3.6_Adwaita_theme are of any help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using different values for `tooltip_bg_color` in GTK2 and GTK3. In `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` you have `#ffffaf`, while in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` you have `#f5f5c5`.

If you want the lighter yellow (like your Firefox screenshot) in GTK3 apps, use `#ffffaf` in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css`.