# Different appearance between gtk3 and gtk2

Tags: 16.04, gtk, window, gtk3, gnome-shell

In the following image there are two windows both out of focus which should look the same, but instead the back one has a more darker (higher contrast?) appearance.

[image]

- Back window: nautilus (gtk3)
- Front window: gufw (gtk2)

The only clue that I have found is that all the darker ones (windows with the problem) are made with gtk3.

Note that this happened the last month (from an auto update?), before that all windows looked like the front one.

Also note that this not a theme specific, all themes have the same problem.

System: Ubuntu 16.04, gnome-shell 3.18.5

Comment: Did you saw [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718547/gtk3-and-gtk2-tooltip-background-color-difference)?

Comment: Yes, my problem is in the whole window and not only at the tooltip. Also I didn't change anything, some update probably caused it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed automatically with a software update at 20/10/2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 (I'm not sure witch package was...)

Answer (score 1):

I am **absolutely** *certain* this is a theme issue. When you do an update, depending on what repositories you have added, your GTK 3.x version can get updated making **existing** GTK3.x themes incompatible due to changes with GTK 3.x styles.

What GTK version are you using? Can you please run: `dpkg -l libgtk-3-0` and let us know?

The fix for this is to create a **gtk-3.xx** folder in the theme folder of your theme while replacing the .**xx** with the version number of GTK, for instance **gtk-3.20** and create a file called *gtk.css* and add the correct settings but doing this manually is tedious so you need to find an existing one that matches your version of GTK and edit that one. You can start with downloading the Arc theme.

Here is an example:

[image]

When GTK gets updated, some CSS property tags get replaced with different tags.

Comment: This is not the reason of the problem because: all themes have the same problem, the difference is not in a color but on some weird color distortion (It looks like higher contrast). (however I have gtk3.18  and I dont think is the reason...)