# texstudio tooltip is solid black instead of texfield

Tags: qt5

The little tooltip when hovering over some fields in TeXstudio show solid black instead of giving more detailed information.

[image]

My guess is that this is related some java stuff - but I'm not sure how to figure this out?
This is probably not necessarily related to TeXstudio but maybe to software compiled with Qt 5.5.1?

I'm on a pretty brand new install of Ubuntu 16.04. The same program runs flawlessly on my new Ubuntu 16.04 install on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been answered in other posts as well: https://askubuntu.com/a/101913/6278

That is,

```
sudo apt install gnome-color-chooser
```

run gnome-color-chooser and then select the ticks in the 'Tooltip' section of tab 'Specific'.