# How to change tooltip background color on Eclipse?

Tags: unity, eclipse, colors

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and latest Eclipse Neon. When I hover some code, I got my tooltip background black and my text orange. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383467/eclipse-javadoc-background-color-is-black) I must change colors at OS level. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity) I saw how to edit colors at OS level. However it didn't work. Even changing Ubuntu Theme, changing tooltip color on Eclipse. I'm using Ambiance right now.

Answer (score 1):

(Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40360725/)

I have verified that

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

is a viable, albeit suboptimal, workaround in **Ubuntu 16.10** and **Eclipse 4.6.1** when the desktop appearance uses the **BlueMenta** themes, with no additional tweaks required.

Tweaking the gtk-3.0 css files didn't work for me.

Other users have had better luck with the scripts [in this project](https://github.com/KiranMohan/eclipse-gtk3-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but after some annoying trials (mostly for older Eclipses with GTK2) a simple solution for brand new eclipse 2019-06 and perhaps for other eclipse versions using GTK3:

1. Install the color-themes-plugin via

   Help>Install New Software

   Add: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update
2. use the plugin via

   Window>Preferences>General>Appearance>Color Theme

   choose any other then default-color-theme, apply and close Dialog
3. If you still want to use Default-Theme: reopen Dialog and switch back to default