# Customizing tooltips in Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: themes, mate, customization, ubuntu-mate, tooltip

I am using Ubuntu Mate 20.04
How can I customize the appearance (i.e. background, font color... ) of tooltips?
Maybe through `dconf-editor` or command line?

Comment: You can install [Gtk2](https://www.mate-look.org/browse/cat/136) and [Gtk3](https://www.mate-look.org/browse/cat/135) themes on Mate and if you want to create your own themes , take a look at [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/oomox-customize-and-create-your-own-gtk2-gtk3-themes/). Also there's a nice program to inspect gtk themes called [The widget laboratory](https://launchpad.net/twl)

Comment: And I don't think it's possible to change it via command line because themes have lots of png files that cover the backgrounds like windows decorations , tooltips , menus , etc.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I am aware of the themes one is able to install at mate. My question refers specifically to the customization of tooltips. Thanks for your time in answering

Comment: @obaino I have refreshed my [old post](https://askubuntu.com/a/403988/66509) about yellow tooltips, you can follow it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install  [Gtk2](https://www.mate-look.org/browse/cat/136) and [Gtk3](https://www.mate-look.org/browse/cat/135) themes and most of them has a structure like this :

```
$tree . -d
.
├── assets
├── gnome-shell
│   └── assets
├── gtk-2.0
│   ├── apps
│   └── assets
├── gtk-3.0
├── metacity-1
└── xfwm4
```

In the `gtk-3.0` directory you can find a file named `gtk.css` . Open it with your favorite text editor and search for `ToolTips`. There should be some properties like this :

```
tooltip {
   padding: 4px;
   /* not working */
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px black; 
}

tooltip.background {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); 
}

tooltip decoration {
     background-color: transparent; 
}
tooltip * {
     padding: 4px;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: white; 
}
```

You can change the background color of your tooltips via the `background-color` property.

And in the `gtk-2.0` directory there's file named `gtkrc` which might contain a line like this :

```
# Tooltip colors
gtk-color-scheme = "tooltip_fg_color:#ffffff\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000"
```

If you want to change the tooltip background color for a gtk2 program ( they are very rare by now) you can adjust it.

You can change the theme via command line without the need to log-out and log-back . For example for a theme called [Sweet](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1253385/) :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Sweet
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Sweet
```

Happy hacking :)

EDIT : These are just for Gtk apps . But you haven't mentioned that you want to change the tooltips of Gtk or Qt apps . So if you want to customize Qt5 apps you can use a nice theme engine called [Kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum) which is very customizable and is SVG based , so you can edit the background color of the tooltips via editing the theme files with something like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)

Comment: @DKBose Edited the typo . Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: All this will work, but it is safer to change the theme files in `~/.config` directory of current user.

Comment: @N0rbert AFAIK gtk themes go to either /usr/share/themes/ or ~/.themes not ~/.config . Do you mean that we should put css files in ~/.config ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi He means to edit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css or ~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtk.css

Comment: @obaino, yes "to edit ~/.config/gtk-3/gtk.css or ~/.config/gtk-2/gtk.css " . Thanks :)

Comment: @N0rbert OK. Does it override current themes settings ? and if yes , then how can you apply a theme ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I have edited your answer to include what I mean. Yes, it overrides current theme. +1 from me :)

Comment: @N0rbert So after that using themes will make no sense. What's the problem with using ~/.themes directory ? I think it's better to start off with a theme and then begin hacking. This makes more room for customization.

Comment: @N0rbert The answer at this point is kind of meaningless I think. At the beginning and at the end we're talking about themes and in the middle we're working with ~/.config . I think we have to update the answer either to adapt it to your opinion or mine .

Comment: OK, please adapt to your original ideas about ~/themes.